# I've found a small error in the Node running documentation, do I correct that, and if so, how?

Tags: cardano-node, documentation

I installed the Cardano node today and found a small error in the documentation.
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/

Basically, the config file for the Alonzo era needs to be added (alonzo-genesis.json).

There was an update page button that would allow me to do it, but it requires me to have a Github account, which I don't have.

Comment: Have you considered creating a GitHub account? It's free. Sorry if this comment sounds snarky, I don't mean for it to come off that way.

Comment: I appreciate your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great job in finding a gap in the documentation.

Signing up for a Github account and submitting a Pull Request (via the update page button you already found) is indeed the way to go. It allows the team to review your proposed changes and once approved automatically deploy these so your edits become live.

Comment: alright, I guess I better bite the bullet. Thank you for the encouragement

Comment: Turned out I still had an account (I'm dying with embarrassment). It started all sorts of automated shenanigans. I hope I did it right